# Highlight scroll bar of textbox

Tags: vb.net, scroll, textbox, highlight

I'm currently working on a VB.NET application and I would like to highlight the scroll bar of a textBox (only when it is enable).

However, I don't want to highlight the entire control.

**Example :**

[image]   **==>**   [image]

I will appreciate any suggestions to do it or a workaround.

Comment: I'm assuming that this is WinForms?  Is there a reason that you want to do this?  Is it just to show to the user that there is more data?  If so, why not show a tooltip saying 'Scroll to see more data'?  In general meddling with the colours of standard windows elements isn't a great idea as it may affect users who have accessibility requirements.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder In fact, sometimes there are more data and sometimes not. I would like to do something to highlight the scroll bar when there are more data. Because the scroll bar is always visible but not always usefull. Should I check the length of my textBox and set the scroll property "None" to "Vertical" ?

Comment: I've flagged this as duplicate, not as a criticism of your question but to redirect other users.  There are VB.NET, C# and workaround solutions for that question.

Comment: @OldBoyCoder Okay, thank you, it works very well ;)